# How to extract only first match with regexp?

Tags: regex, d

Here is string examples:

```
<option value="20150110.1932.mtsat_2.visir.bckgr.NW_Pacific_Overview.DAYNGT.jpg">20150110.1932.mtsat_2.visir.bckgr.NW_Pacific_Overview.DAYNGT.jpg</option>
<option value="20150110.1901.mtsat_2.visir.bckgr.NW_Pacific_Overview.NGT.jpg">20150110.1901.mtsat_2.visir.bckgr.NW_Pacific_Overview.NGT.jpg</option>
```

expected out:

```
20150110.1932.mtsat_2.visir.bckgr.NW_Pacific_Overview.DAYNGT.jpg
20150110.1901.mtsat_2.visir.bckgr.NW_Pacific_Overview.NGT.jpg
```

I need extract only first matches of file name from string without quote symbols . How can I do it?

the pattern is first 6 digits and end with jpg

I am programming on D.

I have a lot of variants. And all of them are cripple. One of them:

```
(="[0-9]{8}).+(\")
```

Comment: Can you post the code you already have?

Comment: which lang are you running? What about html parsers?

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: On D. For my case parser is big overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=>)([0-9]{8}.+)(?=<)
```

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iQ2kL1/1)

Answer (score 4):

I know you don't want to use a html parser, but I want to show how simple that is for people in the future who find this question.

regex kinda sorta works for html sometimes, but there's a lot of things it doesn't to: it would leave html entities (`&amp;` for example) undecoded and extracting the right tag can be hard. A HTML parser makes it easy and correct (and IMO more readable):

My dom.d is does a decent job on html, so I'll show how to use it.

Grab dom.d from my github:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/dom.d

( and if you are parsing tag soup from random non UTF-8 websites, characterencodings.d too: https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/characterencodings.d )

Then you can do it like this:

```
import arsd.dom;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    auto document = new Document("your html string here");
    foreach(option; document.querySelectorAll("option"))
         writeln(option.value); // or option.innerText
}
```

Compile with `dmd yourfile.d dom.d`. (add characterencodings.d to the command line if you need to handle non utf-8 too)

`querySelectorAll` works like CSS selectors, similar to the same function in Javascript and in jQuery, so you can put in context too to extract the option tags from the rest of the html document.

Comment: Big thanks for you parser, could you make DUB package and rename it to some other more logical name? I have plans to use it in future. Also please add more very simple examples for such people like I.

Answer (score 2):

```
\b\d{8}[^" ]*\.jpg(?![^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/20

Comment: The output is not that I expect... please look again at example that I expect to get.

Comment: Thanks! But solution from Seven is shorter.

Comment: @user1432751 that is actually hard bound.if there's a space after `>` or something after `.jpg` till `<` it will capture all.See https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/21 but if the format is fixed its fine